# Codeigniter Datamapper not running get rules on fields with NULL values

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

I'm using [Datamapper](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/) v1.8.2 with Codeigniter v2.1.2 and have a ["get" rule](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/getrules.html) that doesn't seem to run on fields with `NULL` values. Here's the model:

```
class Page extends Datamapper {

    public $validation = array(
        'name' => array(
            'rules' => array('required'),
            'get_rules' => array('get_page_name')
        )
    );

    function _get_page_name($field)
    {
        $this->$field = 'TESTING '.$this->id;
    }

}
```

Example code:

```
$page = new Page();
foreach ($page->get() as $p) echo $p->name;
```

When the table field `name` has any non-null value including an empty string it works fine outputting something like `TESTING 358`, but when the value is `NULL` (which is the default value for this field), it outputs nothing. There is no difference using `get_iterated()`.

I guess I could work around this by changing the default value, but I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong or missed something in the documentation, or maybe it's a bug? Does anyone know what the issue is?

Also, if someone could point me to the proper thread in the CI forums for Datamapper 1.8.2 support that would be great, I'm trying to find it and getting lost in a maze of links to threads for old versions of DM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `allow_null` to the `get_rules` array to make this work. I'm not sure about the intent of the creator but this is [how get_rules are implemented](https://github.com/WanWizard/sparks-datamapper/blob/master/libraries/datamapper.php#L6398-L6400) (however i don't see it mentioned in the docs).

Comment: That was it, thanks! Searching Google for "codeigniter datamapper allow_null" only returned results that were DM source code, so I guess there is no documentation of this? Even this page didn't turn up, and usually SO posts are at the top of the results. Not that I would have known to search for "allow_null" beforehand, just checking if it was documented.

Comment: I've never seen documentation about this, just stumbled upon it once during debugging. I guess it's not documented more than that two lines of comment.

Comment: Next time when you bump into something like this, please be so kind to create an issue for this on bitbucket, so it can be fixed.